# Can not install Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: boot

I am trying to install UBUNTU 22.04 on my  laptop SSD and on my external USB SSD.
Currently:

BIOS
Version
V1.13
Date
3/2/2018
MOTHERBOARD
Manufacturer
Acer
Model
Ptero_SK
Version
V1.13
OPERATING SYSTEM
Edition
Microsoft Windows 10 Home (64-bit)
Version (Build)
21H2 (10.0.19044)

I have BIOS in UEFI boot
SSD are  GPT

Any idea why ubuntu wont boot and show on disks?

I tried both to install on my internal  disk  as dual boot with win10  and later on external USB  SSD  .
Both installation were completed and messages  state they are succesful.

However wen rebooting in my BIOS F12 key pressing only windows boo manager shows and can boot only win10.

when I plug in installation USB it shows   as Linux when pressing F12 key and can boot OK.

What wrong I am doing ?

Comment: Please describe what stops you from installing Ubuntu. Do you get any errors or what are the symptoms ?

Comment: no stops no errors . I can not boot to Ubuntu in BIOS .
I attach

Comment: Do be aware of bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379 if installing to the USB, and add yourself to the "does this affect me" list. Several workarounds are in the bug comments.

Comment: I followed official tutorial . As I described bios will not show ubuntu  boot when pressing F12 key.
However, it  shows it for USB installation  media.

Both installations were succesful  e.i. on ext USB SSD. and as dual boot on internal disk.

Something wrong with by BIOS settings?
I disabled secure boot  in BIOS.